# how to change the position of the added itemtemplate in gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

I have a gridview with a stored proc datasource
when i try to fill out the datagrid, i cannot control the position of the columns, when i add an additional item template, it is automatically positioned on the right but i want it to be on the left side. what should i do?

i want the edit linkbuttons to be placed on the left after the date total

Gridview Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsSched">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField> 
       <ItemTemplate> &nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton> &nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">Cancel</asp:LinkButton> 
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

i've got this right by using the rowdatabound event

```
protected void ListView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Retrieve row
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;

    // Intitialize TableCell list
    List cells = new List();

    foreach (DataControlField column in ListView1.Columns)
    {
        // Retrieve first cell
        TableCell cell = row.Cells[0];

        // Remove cell
        row.Cells.Remove(cell);

        // Add cell to list
        cells.Add(cell);
    }

    // Add cells
    row.Cells.AddRange(cells.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsSched">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>

                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

Comment: btw the dsSched which is my datasource is a stored proc so i cannot use bound fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[GridView.RowStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowstyle.aspx) property and set `:horizontal-align` to left.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i think it is not the right approach, i got my answer anyways but thank you

Comment: @Dave Can you rephrase your question, are you dynamically adding template ?What actually you are doing is confusing me?

Comment: ok im sorry, first i have my gridview databinded with a stored proc datasource. then i need an column that handles my edit and cancel button on the left side of the gridview, i try to add the column i need manually but it was automatically positioned on the right side.